# How to delete Simperium bucket programatically

Tags: simperium

Is it possible to delete a Bucket / Entity in Simperium? I can see how to delete all the contents of a bucket, but not how to remove the bucket completely.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, Simperium only provides an API to delete a bucket's contents, but not the entity bucket itself.

May i ask you what do you need to accomplish?.